# How do I wrap Python's input() function to fixed-length bounds?

Tags: python

The title can be a little misleading, so let me explain what I'm trying to do:

Python 3.5's `input()` function reads plaintext keyboard input. It does not stay on one line, or wrap to a specific width.

Say I have this "textbox":

```
+----------+
|          |
+----------+
```

And then enter "some text":

```
+----------+
| ome text |
+----------+
```

How would I do this?

Edit: My intentions are keeping the text inside the box while typing, not after it.

Comment: post-processing on the return of input()

Comment: Not terribly easily, I suspect. Even harder without any code. :)

Comment: `input()` reads the *standard input* stream, which might not be a keyboard.  You would need to use terminal handling rather than `input()`, for example https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not think this is possible with `input()`. Something like [prompt_toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit) might work, but definitely not from `input()` (which actually lets the terminal echo entered characters).